# Air conditioner register leaking

Tags: air-conditioning

I had my roof repaired and they had to lift my AC unit. Now I have condensation leaking from a register. What caused this?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like they may not have leveled the ac unit and the condensate is dripping into the your vent, if they did level the unit they may have moved the drain and it plugged up.
In my state a roof mounted system requires a drain line to the edge of the roof at a minimum.
Checking the condensate drain would be my first check.